# "Pretty" URLs Not Working

Tags: .htaccess, pretty-urls

I'm trying to remove the ".php" extension from the URLs of a site using this code (which I admit I copy/pasted from other questions here) in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Other lines of the .htaccess file do work, for instance, I have an error redirect and:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, I know the .htaccess file is in service in general.

I don't know what could go wrong in this area, so I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting. Does anyone have pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem with your rules? that people can still access your .php files? because what your rule does is allow them to access your site like `domain.com/index` which would internally redirect to `index.php` but still allows direct access to php as well.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I want users to be able to type in, for example, "domain.com/page" and see what actually exists at "domain.com/page.php". I'd like the ".php" to be hidden from the user, basically. But it doesn't work like I thought it might. If I type in "domain.com/page", I get a 404 error instead of seeing what's at "domain.com/page.php". Thanks for any help you might have. I'm completely new to htaccess files beyond copy-pasting a rule here and there. I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting this or if the rules I've copied here are even syntactically accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your domain account is `/home/youraccount/public_html`, your `.htaccess` would be inside the `public_html` folder with the following content:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# First we redirect the www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# now we redirect phpless URLs internally to the php
# if folder does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# but the file exists and ends with .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
# redirect to name.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

**NOTE:** If you have more rules this may conflict so I would have to look at the rest of your rule but basically the above should work as expected.

You will be able to access both:

```
domain.com/index
```

and

```
domain.com/index/
```

And it would redirect to your file `index.php`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot for your help. Can you say what in particular was wrong with the code I was using or was it just the wrong path altogether?

Comment: @leewaters well 1 thing is that you're using `^(.*)$` which would try to match things like `domain.com/index/` with `domain.com/index/.php` which would not work because of the ending `/` aside from that it should work. On my rule what I do is, I get anything that is not a `/` and make the last `/` optional, it would be pretty much the same as if u used `^(.*)/?$`